# Запись и чтение БД EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Дано:

```
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Publication
{
  private int authorId;

  public Publication(int id, string content, int authorId)
  {
    Id = id;
    Content = content;
    this.authorId = authorId;
  }

  public Publication(User author)
  {
    authorId = author.Id;
  }

  public int Id { get; private set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  public User Author
  {
    get
    {
      using DataBase db = new DataBase();
      return db.Users.Single(u => u.Id == authorId);
    }
  }
}
```

Таблицы в бд: 
Users: 
Id | int 
Name | varchar(32) 
Age | int

Publications: 
Id | int 
Content | nvarchar(500) 
AuthorId | int

Вопрос:
Как мне при чтении из БД вызывать конструктор `public Publication(int id, string content, int authorId)`, а при записи в БД записывать свойство `Author.Id` ?